# Why does mesh not follow bone perfectly?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, weight-painting

My mesh is parented to an armature.  But when I rotate the armature upperarm, the mesh's upper arm does not follow the armature fully.

What are the likely causes and how to fix this?

Thank you very much for your help.[image]

Comment: You are in weight paint mode, you have to change the mode to pose

Comment: could you share your .blend? it would make investigating the problem easier

Comment: Here's my .blend:

Comment: I tried dragging .blend on Blendexchange, but it wont upload.  So, I went to pasteall.org, and got this: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51083

Comment: I had similar issue . I deleted other vertex groups that are not suppose to be included for he particular mesh. it was the eyelid that I was having issues with. so I deleted the vertex group for finger and lips for that mesh, weight painted and it worked.
N.B. I didn't delete the bone group

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a bit messy in your vertex groups and bone weights, for example if I select a group like *Chest* (which is duplicated by the way), but also some other bones, then press the *Select* button, I can see that the arms are part of these groups, maybe not enough so I can see it in *Weight Paint* mode, but enough to have influence on it. So maybe check all your groups, remove these vertices from these groups, or delete some bones and/or weight paint again...

[image]

Comment: Thx.  I dont know why it happens.  I just weight parent normally.  This is the 1st time this happens.  Is there any easier way to rectify this beside manually dealing with this vertex group?

Comment: Funny... It is easier to just delete all the vertex groups.. then auto weight parent again.  It is all fixed now.  Still I do not know what the original cause of this occurance.  If anyone has some idea, please suggest.  So, we can prevent it from the get-go.  Thx~